# MongoDB Replica Sets

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and have little experience at the moment so need a little help, we are looking at setting up MongoDB with a standard replica set.  This contains, as I understand it, a primary and two secondary.  My question is this, will the primary, and two secondary definitely require a different server or VM for example (I have read this is the case but still not sure) as we will be performing a fair number of writes each time a user logs into the system.

Currently we are just looking into the feasibility of this set up at the moment and nothing has been decided yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: definitely separate else you might as well be using single server

Comment: Thanks Sammaye, we will be looking at introducing more than one set in the long run.  Is this also the case for the primary and the two secondary's? Will each of these require separate VMs?  I am thinking about the scaling issues we may encounter down the line.

Comment: Of course, also replica sets are not really designed to scale but rather create availability, sharding is more designed for scaling

Comment: thank you kindly, you have been very helpful